# Excel Macro to rounding number

Tags: excel, rounding, vba

I use excel formula 
=ROUNDUP(A1,0) 
but here it rounds to next number.
I need to round numbers like this

253.36 should be rounded to 253
253.51 should be rounded to 254

if greater than .50 round to next number other wise next number?
Is it possible?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

use `=ROUND(A1, 0)` instead. This rounds decimal numbers in the normal way.

I assume in your specification you mean *if greater than or equal to .50* round to the next number. If you really want .50 to round downwards then let me know; as that requires some trickery.